# Not able to Format USB from all possibilities

Tags: usb-flash-drive, format, diskpart

[image: Issue fromDiskpart]

[image: Issue from Disk Management]

I have a Sandisk Pendrive of 16GB. Unfortunately, I filled the pen drive full except for 0.98 GB free space. Now when I am trying to use that USB drive in my PC, it is just loading and then I get an error saying something like "USB not recognized".

I also used the command `format F:` to format the USB drive.

I even tried to uninstall the drive from `devmgmt.msc` and also drivers got updated. I am still facing the issue.

I also tried disk part. When I search for disks using `list disk` it takes a long time and giving error as virtual disk service error.

Comment: i'd suspect that it's broken. if you can't format it but you can others. It might help to be administrative at the time.

Comment: The 0.98 it's the free space Windows Explorer it's saying you have free on the usb ? Or it's the number you calculate thiking about the USB should have 16GB ready to use for you. A 16GB usb drive should show you it has 14.7GB available only. This it's due the way the manufacturers calculate the space of devices. Instead of using 1024 as multiplier they use 1000. So the real available space always it's less than the announced.

Comment: @NetVicious You wrote "The 0.98 it's the free space Windows Explorer it's saying you have free on the usb ? Or it's the number you calculate thiking about the USB should have 16GB ready to use for you." <--- What are you talking about. He said his 16GB USB is almost full so obviously there aren't 16GB free, he knows that.  And nonse of that has anything to do with his USB not being recognized.

Comment: you can look in disk management and check that it has a letter, though I somewhat doubt that has anything to do with your error messages.

Comment: It's the space shown on My Computer when I insert a USB. After that, it will load automatically and finally says USB not recognized.

Comment: Ok, so lets check the partitions on the USB. Right click on computer, select Manage, select Disk Management. Search your USB drive and tell us how many partitions it has, and if all the space is used by partition(s).

Comment: Try it in another computer to confirm it's actually an issue with the USB drive.

Comment: @barlop Sorry, but he edited the answer and changed what I saw before writing my comment.

Comment: @NetVicious he did not edit any answer. He may have edited his question, but the original of his question is just as clear, he says he is using most of the usb, and he is getting an error about it not being recognized

Comment: @NetVicious it has no partitions as it is USB.

Comment: Just Now I tried in another Laptop.I tried disk part to clean memory allocated. but encountered an error.                                                           Disk Part has encountered an Error: The system cannot find the file specified.See the System Event log for more information.

Comment: @SomaNaresh - It has at least one partition otherwise it wouldn't have a file system.

Comment: Have you tried something like this [tool](http://download.cnet.com/HP-USB-Disk-Storage-Format-Tool/3000-2094_4-10974082.html)?

Comment: @Ramhound It has one partition. F: 14.9GB Healthy (Primary Partition)

Comment: Right, but the device cannot be mounted, thus device has failed.

Comment: Any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

The delay when you do a *list disk* in diskpart is very telling. It indicates that Windows has problems trying to talk to the controller chip inside the stick.

Conclusion: That USB stick is broken. Throw it away.

Comment: I can't throw. Because I have some Personal Documents and Photos that I failed to Upload to Cloud. That's why I needed that one. Otherwise, I can throw without thinking about a minute.

Comment: Is there any way to recover?

Comment: @SomaNaresh - If you cannot mount a volume with a file system then you cannot recover your data.  The drive does not sound like it currently is functioning.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree.

Comment: @Ramhound- Before Loading the Data, it was working fine. This issue came when I load the USB with full data.

Comment: The device failing and you putting data on it has nothing to do with one another.

Comment: Before loading full, I have used that Pendrive for all transfers. I don't know what happened to this After loading. Is this maybe because of full data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Transcend's RecoveRx software available on official transcend website. I think it will definitely work.

Comment: @Amandeep-This software not at all detecting my Pen drive

Comment: Have you tried Gparted and Sd card formatter? I think your pendrive is OK. The drive may be encrypted or something like this. If Windows is picking up pendrive there may not be any hardware problem. Try different tools for formatting your pendrive. Search on internet. Try viewing your pendrive on different OS platform like Linux.